# Rails Engine vs. Rack Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I'm thinking about writing an "add-on" application and releasing it as a gem. However, I'm not sure if I should be writing a Rails Engine or a Rack application. What are the differences and which should I choose?

**Update:** The idea for the application is sort of like a "suggestion box". Your users (or co-workers) can submit suggestions for improvements to your application. Then, when you're ready to work on a new feature, you can attach a cucumber test (or point to the location of one) so the submitter can see when the feature has been completed (tests passing). So ideally, you could mount this application at `/suggestions` or where ever and get all this functionality.

Comment: Andrew, this will be a much better question if you give some details about what kind of add-on application you intend to write. It is too vague the way it is now.

Comment: @edgerunner I added an update describing the idea for the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Rails Engine, you generally have the power of Rails at your disposal, It is inherently a Rack Application because of Rails.

Generally a Rack Application will have a lot of less(or more) bells and whistles compared to Rails. You will have to figure which Rack components to use and how to setup the middleware if needed.

If you need a quick and easily testable solution, go for Rails Engines.

Otherwise building a Rack Application will be supremely more fun as compared to a Rails Engine.

Comment: well... "supremely more fun" sounds pretty hard to resist. =/

Comment: So can you run a Rails engine as if it were a rack application, outside of a normal Rails application?

Comment: Can we run a rack application inside a Rails Engine?